# Bicep conditionally add configs to azure function

Tags: azure-bicep

I would like to add some configs to azure function. But I don't want to add them if they are empty strings. Some example code:

```
param functionAppName string

param someApiConfig string = ''

resource defaultFunctionAppAppsettings 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2018-11-01' = {
  name: '${functionAppName}/appsettings'
  properties: {
    FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION: 'v4'
    FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME: 'dotnet'
    ...

    if(someApiConfig != '') ApiConfig: someApiConfig <- How to do it only if someApiConfig is set?
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76063125/4167200

Comment: You can merge objects based on a condition

Answer (score 0):

To check whether the given string is empty, you can use [empty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-object#empty) function from bicep functions list.

If you would like to use for the entire **site config** resource, the **`empty`** function must be included in the way shown below.

```bash
param  someApiConfig  string = ''
resource  appcreate  'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01'  existing = {
   name: 'rithfuncy'
}

resource defaultFunctionAppAppsettings 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2018-11-01' = if(!empty(someApiConfig)){
name: 'appcreate/appsettings'
properties: {
FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION: 'v4'
FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME: 'dotnet'
dependson: [
    appcreate
     ]
   }
}
```

*Deployed successfully with the above changes.*

[image]

If you would like to use only for the **app settings** resource, the **`empty`** function should be included in the below manner.

```bash
appSettings:[(!empty(someApiConfig))
  configsettingname: value
]
```